# Looking for free tools for exporting a report on disk usage as HTML or PDF

Tags: disk-analysis

As per the title, I'm looking for a software that can be scheduled to analyze a network path (an AWS FSX path to be exact) and generate a detailed report on the folder sizes to have it emailed at a daily basis.

I'm aware software such as Treesize has this feature but the export options are only available on the paid versions. It would be very helpful if you could suggest a free software or monitoring tool that could be automated to at least periodically to export a report to disk as HTML/PDF.

Thanks